# Help in understanding the solution : Profit and Loss Problem

Tags: contest-math

> On buying a pen, the shopkeeper gives three refills free. On buying a
> pen and six refills, the shopkeeper gives additional four refills
> free. If the equivalent discount is the same in both cases, then how
> many refills will be equal in value to a pen?

The solution provided for this problem is as follows :-
Let the cost of pen be $p$ and that of refill be $r$.
Then $\frac{3r}{p}=\frac{4r}{p+6r} \Rightarrow p=18r$

I am not able to understand how did the first fraction relation came up. Please help me understand that.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The equation is the translation of "the equivalent discount is the same in both cases" into math.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is that $\frac{3r}{p}$ and $\frac{4r}{p+6r}$ both measure $$\frac{\text{value of free stuff you got}}{\text{amount you paid}}$$ in the two transactions. If you buy a pen and get three free refills, you paid $p$ and got $3r$ worth of free stuff. If you buy a pen plus six refills, and get four free refills, you paid $p+6r$ and got $4r$ worth of free stuff.

This ratio indirectly corresponds to the "equivalent discount" in percentages.

---

Here's maybe a more intuitive solution. Assume equivalent discounts get you:

- $3$ free refills, if you buy a pen;
- $4$ free refills, if you buy a pen and $6$ refills.

Then the extra $6$ refills you bought in the second case are getting you $1$ extra free refill. So we immediately conclude that the extra free stuff is worth $\frac16$ of what you paid for.

If $3$ free refills are $\frac16$ of the price of a pen, then $3 \cdot 6 = 18$ refills are equal to the price of a pen.